# What if the number of values in dataset is different from total dimension of dataset in python?

Tags: python, dataset, dimension

I am working on with 'ERA5-Land monthly averaged data from 1950 to present' for total precipitation and evaporation.

I found out that the number of values in the dataset is 1,306,863,104.
[1306863104 values with dtype=float32]
However, the total dimension of the dataset is 864*1801*3600 (time, latitude, longitude respectively) =5,601,830,400.

Have you guys ever worked with such data?

I want to calculate SPEI index (using climate_indices package), but the error code is like that they cannot reshape 1,306,863,104 data into (864,1801,3600). Because of this issue, I am stuck in..
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself.
It was because of the dtype.
Default dtype of built-in function was int type.
The number of value exceeds the range that integer can represent.
5,601,830,400 > 2^32

Therefore, I set the dtype to float.

Then, It worked well.